# Stylus jeet doesn't work anymore

Tags: node.js, stylus, jeet-grid

In one single day i got this error. It doesn't work anymore for me.

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp   = require('gulp'),
    stylus = require('gulp-stylus'),
    jeet   = require('jeet');

gulp.task('default', function () {

    gulp.src('assets/*.styl')
        .pipe(stylus({
            use: [ jeet() ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/'));
});
```

theme.styl

```
@import "jeet"

.page
  span(1/2)
```

---

```
failed to locate @import file jeet.styl
```

Full error – http://pastebin.com/KuZ4ZPwK

Comment: What version of jeet you have? There is a issue starting at 6.1.3 https://github.com/mojotech/jeet/issues/129

Comment: @blonfu latest – 6.1.4

Comment: try using a earlier version, `6.1.1` or  `6.1.2`: `npm install jeet@6.1.2 --save-dev`

Comment: @blonfu yup that seems to do it for me- thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
npm i github:mojotech/jeet#master --save-dev
```

or

```
npm i jeet@6.1.2 --save-dev
```

---

[[GitHub] Jeet 6.1.4 + Stylus doesn't work #494](https://github.com/mojotech/jeet/issues/494)